# ListView with images and text in android

Tags: java, android

i am trying to implement a listview with images and text in each entry in android

however i get a Message:" your app must stopped..."

here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.temp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

 EditText edittext;
 ListView listview;

 String[] text = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
   "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

 int[] image = { R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo,
   R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo,
   R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo };

 int textlength = 0;

 ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<Integer> image_sort = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
  listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, image));

  edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
  {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
   {

   }

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int count, int after)
   {

   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int before, int count)
   {

    textlength = edittext.getText().length();
    text_sort.clear();
    image_sort.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
     if (textlength <= text[i].length())
     {
      if (edittext.getText().toString().
   equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
      {
       text_sort.add(text[i]);
       image_sort.add(image[i]);
      }
     }
    }

    listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter
     (text_sort, image_sort));

   }
  });
 }

 class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {

  String[] data_text;
  int[] data_image;

  MyCustomAdapter()
  {

  }

  MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, int[] image)
  {
   data_text = text;
   data_image = image;
  }

  MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> text, ArrayList<Integer> image)
  { 

   data_text = new String[text.size()];
   data_image = new int[image.size()];

   for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++)
   {
    data_text[i] = text.get(i);
    data_image[i] = image.get(i);
   }

  }

  public int getCount()
  {
   return data_text.length;
  }

  public String getItem(int position)
  {
   return null;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position)
  {
   return position;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {

   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   View row;

   row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

   TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
   ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row
     .findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

   textview.setText(data_text[position]);
   imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

   return (row);

  }
 }

}
```

and here is my listview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Israel News"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and here my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                  android:hint="Search">                               
                </EditText>

                <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                 </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the logcat:

```
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.temp/com.example.temp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.example.temp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-03 11:47:02.053: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  ... 11 more
```

i really dont know what is the problem yet..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared edittext as an EditText but you have not initialized it. And when you are trying to perform the addWatcher on it, you are essentially performing it on null. Just try this :

```
edittext = new EditText(this);
```

or

```
edittext = (EditText) findByViewId(R.id.EditText01);
```

Comment: thanks alot, it solved my problem, i also want that the picture will be stretched to the whole entry of listview, what do i need to changed in order to do that? this is how my listview looks like now: img252.imageshack.us/img252/4043/listview.png

Answer (score 2):

your edittext is null, because you haven't get the Edit text,

get EditText like this
Add this line before adding TextChangedListener to your edittext

```
editext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using uninitialized property edittext on line 45 in MainActivity. Add this line before line 45:

```
edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
```

Performance tip: check ViewHolder pattern to make scrolling of your list more smooth: http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166

Comment: thanks alot, it solved my problem, i also want that the picture will be stretched to the whole entry of listview, what do i need to changed in order to do that? this is how my listview looks like now:  http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/4043/listview.png

Answer (score 0):

Your not initialized edittext. By default in java if you declare any variable, and if your not initialize any thing, it will have some predefined value. In java by default any object if your not assigning it will have null value.  If you want to use that object for calling function/accessing the its data members its throws NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION.

Answer (score -2):

You are getting a nullpoint exeception.Try to debug it and check line 45 or where the null pointer is coming.

Comment: i tried to debug it, however i didnt find the problem..hope someone help me

Comment: I pointed out the line where u will get the null. I tried your code and its giving null pointer in Edittext as pointed by others.